# Why is the euler characteristic of a sphere 2?

Tags: general-topology, spheres, polyhedra

When calculating the Euler Characteristic of any regular polyhedron the value is 2. Since a sphere is homoeomorphic to all regular polyhedrons, the sphere ought to have a Euler Characteristic of 2 as well.

So:

$V-E+F=2$

holds true

A sphere obviously do not have vertices nor edges, which ought to mean they have 2 faces, which i assume are the inside and outside.

If that is the case, why dont you count the inside and outside as two seperate faces on any of the other regular polyhedrons? A tetrahedron for example only has 4 faces.

If not, then where is the other face.

Comment: You should compute $V-E+F$ on a triangulation of the sphere to get the Euler characteristic.

Comment: If one calculates the Euler characteristic by counting cells in a CW decomposition, the easiest one is to attach a 2-cell to a point to get a sphere. Then the number of 0-cells is 1, the number of 1-cells is 0, and the number of 2-cells is 1. So we get 1-0+1=2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For any triangulation of the sphere, it is true that $V-E+F=2$, where $V$ is the number of vertices in the triangulation, $E$ the number of edges in the triangulation and $F$ the number of faces in the triangulation. For example, consider the triangulation below:

[image]

There are $6$ vertices, $12$ edges and $8$ faces, so $V-E+F=6-12+8=2$.

There are also more complicated definitions of the Euler Characteristic in terms of homology or number of cells in each dimension in a CW complex. It can be defined as
$$\chi(X)=\sum(-1)^n\mathrm{rank}(H_n(X))\,.$$

Answer (score 8):

Consider a sequence of simple configurations on
the surface of a sphere. Start with two points on
the surface and connect them by two edges. This
divides the surface of the sphere into two faces.
Thus $\,2-2+2=2.\,$ Now remove one of the edges.
This leaves only one face on the sphere. Thus
$\,2-1+1=2\,$. Now move the two points together
until they merge into only a single point and there
is no edge. Thus $\,1-0+1=2\,$ again.

NOTE: Topology enters at the first step with the
two edges. On a sphere, they divide the surface
into two faces which are topologically disks, but
for other topologically different surfaces this
may not be the case. For example, a torus requires
more edges to be able to form faces which are
topologically disks.

Comment: i didnt realise this before, but when i tried to explain the solution to a friend this came up and was actually a really good and intuitive explanation! Thanks 

Comment: @Somos is there any reason why we can't apply this same reasoning to any other surfaces? For example, if you apply the above to the torus, that will show the Euler Characteristic of a torus is 2, but that is obviously not the case since it is in fact 0. I don't see what will change going from the sphere to the torus.

Comment: @Nanoputian You can attempt to apply the same reasoning to other surfaces, but you will have different results. If you attempt this on a torus, then no matter  where you draw the two edges, you will not get two faces, and by face we mean a surface which is topologically a disk. This is because the surface of a sphere is topologically not the same as the surface of a torus.

Comment: @Somos right, yep that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the hash addition formula, we have:

$$ \chi(X \# Y)  = \chi(X) + \chi(Y) - 2$$

We have $X=Y$ here (both spheres) and know $X \# Y = X$ :

$$ \chi(X) = 2 \chi(X) - 2$$

Rearranging,

$$\chi(X) =2$$